# Boolean statement without using if/else statement?

Tags: java, integer, boolean

Need to print a boolean statement that will return
-'true' if input number is within a range of 1 to 100 but 'false' if it's an even number between 40 and 50.

- e.g if you enter 12,45,60,etc...you should get true.
- if you enter 42 or 44 or 48 you should get false.

Here's the code I have so far,
I'm stuck because it prints 'false' if I enter a number that's below 40, e.g 12 or above 50, e.g 60. This is the only part I need help fixing. Beginner in programming here so would appreciate any help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   int value;

    System.out.println("enter number");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    value = scan.nextInt();

    scan.close();


    boolean valuetest, min, max;


    min = (value>0 && value <101);
    max = (value >=40 && value <= 50 && value%2 ==1);

   valuetest= (max && min);
    System.out.println( valuetest);
```

Comment: `valuetest = (value >= 40 && value <= 50) ? (value % 2 == 0) : (value > 0 && value < 101)`

Comment: Does "between 40 and 50" include 40 and 50?

Comment: What do you mean by 'boolean statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second "max" condition only needs to apply to numbers falling into the range of 40 to 50.  Otherwise, odd/even does not matter.  Consider this version:

```java
if (value > 0 && value < 40 ||
    value >= 40 && value <= 50 && value % 2 == 1 ||
    value > 50 && value < 101) {

    System.out.println(valuetest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write code in a different function that will return true/false as below:

```
public bool ResultVal(int value)
{
   if(value >=1 && value <= 100)
   {
     if(value >=40 && value <=50)
     {
        if(value % 2 == 0)
        {
          return false;
        } 
     }
     return true; 
   }
   return false;
}
```

and call the function from your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

   int value;

    System.out.println("enter number");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    value = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Result: " + ResultVal(value));
    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: thank you! it's very helpful to see this version. I still haven't learned most of these stuff yet so it'll be helpful for my future studies.

Comment: You are welcome, can you up vote if this post is helpful for you :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are so few values in the "false" list:

```
boolean valuetest = value >= 1 && value <= 100 
    && !List.of(40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50).contains(value);
```

Readability counts.

`

Comment: what does the ! stand for?

Comment: it means "if the value does not fall in the list of values containing 40, 42, 44, 46, 48 and 50". '!' it is a negation operator